# Looking for a formula to compute $\left\lceil \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rceil$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm looking for a formula to easily compute:
$$ \left\lceil \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rceil $$
The formula shouldn't use any floor, ceil or round function. I'm looking for something "simple".

Comment: Which one?  Floor or ceiling?

Comment: What's wrong with $\operatorname{ceil}$?

Comment: @Ty. ceil. Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @JayJay does a summation count as "simple"?

Comment: @JairTaylor I need to compute something and I've got that thing in the superior extrem of a sum, which isn't easy at all to compute by hand. I'm not interested in programming solutions.

Comment: @Ty. a finite summation, yes. ;)

Comment: Why is that expression itself a simple formula.  Not sure how to make it simpler.

Comment: @JayJay Wolf only gives an infinite sum, and it is only valid if $\frac{x+1}{2}$ is not integer.

Comment: @fleablood me neither, that's why I'm here asking for help

Comment: @JayJay can it include modulo?

Comment: I honestly don't get what you are asking.  Just do it.  why on earth *not* say  "$\frac {x+1}2$ rounded up the the nearest integer"?

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim yes.

Comment: @fleablood because I'm looking for a closed form of a summation which contains the expression I mentioned, which isn't easy to compute in that form.

Comment: @JayJay does my solution do it now?

Comment: IMO, this is looks like an XY question. The solution might lie elsewhere in the problem.

Comment: Why on earth would you think there'd be a formula?  For every real value there is least integer larger or equal to it but there's no other way to express or calculate it than that.  For what it's worth $x$ has a least odd integer greater or equal to it and this expression is the index of that odd number.  (i.e. the odd number is $2n-1$ and this is $n$.

Comment: "Why on earth would you think there'd be a formula?" That's not an appropriate way to express to other people in an educational site. Are you saying my mistake was ASKING a question?

Comment: " contains the expression I mentioned, which isn't easy to compute in that form."  What? It's very easy co calculate.  Add $1$, divide by $2$ and round up.

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out what on earth you are actually *asking*.  I mean this seems like you are asking how to solve $a + b$ without doing addition.

Comment: @fleablood you can do it politely, without the "Why on earth would you think there'd be a formula?" part.

Comment: @fleablood: if that "counts", you can achieve this effect with periodic functions (see my answer). I don't claim that it would be a clever idea.

Comment: @fleablood: $\log(e^a e^b)$, of course ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No closed-form expression with $+,-,\times,\div$ can "emulate" the ceiling function (in particular because these operators are continuous; all they allow are rational fractions). With these basic operators, you would need an expression of infinite size.

Periodic functions and their inverses, like

$$\frac1\pi\arctan(\tan(\pi x))$$ give you access to the fractional part, from which you can build the floor/ceiling. But this is by no means "simple".

The answer is essentially *no way*.

Comment: "No closed-form expression with +,−,×,÷ can "emulate" the ceiling function" Okay. Then what I was looking for isn't possible. I think this will be the closer to a "correct solution". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{x+1}{2}$ isn't an integer, then
$$\left\lceil \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rceil=\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rfloor+1$$
and $$(x+1) \pmod{2}=x+1-2\cdot\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rfloor$$
$$ \iff \left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rfloor=\frac{(x+1)-((x+1) \pmod{2})}{2}$$
$$\implies \left\lceil \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rceil=\frac{(x+1)-((x+1) \pmod{2})}{2}+1$$
Otherwise $\left\lceil \frac{x+1}{2} \right\rceil=\frac{x+1}{2}$

Comment: What's the closed form of $x \pmod 2$?

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim I appreaciate your answer and, even with the mistake, your result was useful in a certain way. Thanks for replying. :)

Comment: Stop denying other's comments that point at your gross mistakes. Your other answer is not unprecedented, this question was asked and answered zillion times.

Comment: @JayJay you're welcome :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't deny any comment, and I accept a mistake I make when I see it. 
Indeed the question was asked and answered a lot, but the solution itself I didn't see it anywhere else.
It'd be nice if you discuss more politely :D

Comment: By the way, $\lceil\frac{x+1}2\rceil=\lfloor\frac{x+1}2\rfloor+1$ is wrong ! This is not your day.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I edited it, thanks again :)

Comment: @fleablood it is $x-2\cdot \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right\rfloor$

Comment: @JayJay Look at the edited version now. If you want to use it in a code or something, you might make it a function and make a condition: if $(x+1)/2 \pmod{1}=0$ then use the second formula, if not use the one with the modulo.